# Pointer to a logger class provide for all other classes?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, logging

I have a Logger class in my C++ application. This class has public methods like `writeDebug(std::string & str)` , can write to a debug output file and it works for me very good. The object is being created on application start by the first main class and there it is stored as a `Logger * myLogger;` object.

Since I have other classes as well, I would like to provide this logging functionality to those classes as well.

Currently I oberhead the myLogger pointer to toher classes in their contructor, and all the other classes store this very same Logger pointer when being created --> all other classes has this `Logger * myLogger` **pointer** stored:

```
Other_XY_Class::Other_XY_Class(Logger * logger, ...) 
: localLoggerPtr{logger} { //.. }
```

==> localLoggerPtr (in class  Other_XY_Class) == myLogger (in main application class)

I can imagine that there is a more convenient / elegant way to handle that ?

Comment: I would use a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if you want one instance shared among many objects.

Comment: Are you asking wheter using a *singleton* or a global variable is a better solution, for example?

Comment: You can think about making `Logger`s methods `static`

Comment: I think what you do is called dependency injection and it is good.

Comment: @prajmus: I don't think making it static is good. That basically makes it a singleton. Why should I only want one logger? Maybe I want to have two different one to log to different files?

Comment: @trenki ok, I get the use case, but I just thought OP wants to have only one object, but doesn't want to share the pointer between classes.

Comment: @trenki `Why should I only want one logger?` Because if you don't need more, then it's simpler. That said, I wouldn't make the memeber function static either. Instead, I'd use a global instance because that's just as simple and doesn't limit you to just one logger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one instance, why not use a Singleton for that?

Something along this lines:

```
class foo {
private:
   void bar();

   static foo Instance;

public:
  static void Bar() { Instance.bar(); }
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this as opposed to just making `bar` static?

Comment: This is hardly a singleton...

Comment: In my Logging class I have already created a private file handle File* file which I use oneach write attempt. How would I access that?

Comment: I like the idea of a singleton, but new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120691/singleton-with-two-getinstance-methods-handing-over-a-parent-pointer