# Singleton with two getInstance() methods handing over a parent pointer?

Tags: c++, logging, static, singleton, overloading

I am still working on my [Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118485/pointer-to-a-logger-class-provide-for-all-other-classes) and I like the idea of a Singleton but my Logger derives frm QDialog, thus I would like to handle my Parent QWidget* MainWindow pointer when I call it first:

```
class Logger : public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT

private:  
  explicit Logger(QWidget* parent = 0);

public:
  static Logger& firstInstance(QWidget* parent = 0) {
       static Logger theInstance(parent);
       return theInstance;
  }
  static Logger& instance() {
       return theInstance;
  }
  //..
}
```

So I would call `Logger::firstInstance(this);` from my MainWindow. And Logger::instance() from elsewhere. But my compiler mocks:

> Error: 'theInstance' was not declared in this scope:
>        return theInstance;

in the second `instance()` method.

Comment: Well, as the compiler says: There is no variable named `theInstance` in your second method. How is the compiler supposed to find it, then?

Comment: Why is the logger a *dialog*? That sounds like a very strange thing for a logger to be.

Comment: Consider to start dislike the idea of Singleton...

Comment: @PiotrNycz When you cant justify your argument, it is sound and smoke

Comment: @molbdnilo I display the output in a seperate dialog

Comment: @MarkZir 1) See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons  2) Your question itself is a prof that world w/out singletons would be simpler...

Answer (score 1):

You should actually call just `firstInstance` from `instance`, since you have static variable in `firstInstance` it will be initialized only on first call, then just returned already initialized variable.

```
  static Logger& instance() {
       return firstInstance();
  }
```

But actually, function `firstInstance` in public interface is bad idea, probably it will be better to make it private and declare `MainWindow` friend class.